# Calling a JavaScript function within HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-earth-plugin

I have the following function which is part of Google Earth API. It generates an image overlay on the map and has to be called multiple times. How do I call this function and give every call a unique id? I thought about something like this:

```
function createScreenOverlay(location, x , y) {
            var screenOverlay = ge.createScreenOverlay('');
            screenOverlay.setIcon(ge.createIcon(''));
            screenOverlay.getIcon().setHref(location); 

            screenOverlay.getOverlayXY().setXUnits(ge.UNITS_FRACTION);
            screenOverlay.getOverlayXY().setYUnits(ge.UNITS_FRACTION);
            screenOverlay.getOverlayXY().setX(.5);
            screenOverlay.getOverlayXY().setY(.5);

              // Set screen position in fractions.
            screenOverlay.getScreenXY().setXUnits(ge.UNITS_PIXELS);
            screenOverlay.getScreenXY().setYUnits(ge.UNITS_PIXELS);
            screenOverlay.getScreenXY().setX(x);  // Random x.
            screenOverlay.getScreenXY().setY(y);  // Random y.

              // Rotate around object's center point.
            screenOverlay.getRotationXY().setXUnits(ge.UNITS_FRACTION);
            screenOverlay.getRotationXY().setYUnits(ge.UNITS_FRACTION);
            screenOverlay.getRotationXY().setX(0.9);
            screenOverlay.getRotationXY().setY(0.5);

              // Rotate by a random number of degrees.
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(screenOverlay);
        };
```

Have this in the HTML: 
`<p id="campusbutton"><p>`

and then once more in the JavaScript section have this calling it:     `document.getElementById("campusbutton").innerHTML=createScreenOverlay(LOCATION, X, Y);`

This does work, however it writes "undefined" Where the `<p>` is suppose to be... obviously `<p>` is the paragraph tag which is why the "undefined" is printed, but is there any other tag I could use? `<div>` doesn't work for some reason.

Thank you!

Comment: Your function has no return value, which means it returns `undefined`.  You send that `undefined` into the `<p>` `.innerHTML`.  What _should_ the `<p>` contents become?

Comment: You should make an example on jsfiddle, it will be easier.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a for loop somewhere!

Comment: Yes I understand that Michael... all I need really is I guess a different tag that can be just a "space" holder or a trigger for the function. The reason I want to do that is so I can give an "id" to each trigger so I can add functionalities to the objects generated from the function above

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, if you want the `campusbutton` to load your overlay then you should use a event like `onclick` to call the function and pass the parameters as required.

```
<p id="campusbutton" onclick="createScreenOverlay(LOCATION, X, Y)"><p>
```

As it is you are setting the innerHTML of the `campusbutton` element to the result of the function `createScreenOverlay`, but the function doesn't return anything so that isn't going to work.

Even if the function did return something, the `KmlScreenOverlay` for example

```
function createScreenOverlay(location, x , y) {
            var screenOverlay = ge.createScreenOverlay('');
            // rest of your code
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(screenOverlay);    
            // return the type
            return screenOverlay;
        };
```

Your innerHTML of the `campusbutton` would still just be the result of this call. Which would be `Object`.

If you want the innerHTML of the `campusbutton` to be the actual Kml of the overlay then ammend the function to return the `KmlScreenOverlay` as above, then change the call to set the innerHTML to the kml representation of the object.

```
document.getElementById("campusbutton").innerHTML=createScreenOverlay(LOCATION, X, Y).getKml();
```